# Getting HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized as a response while using MSAL4J library to perform user create operation on Azure AD

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using following java code for creating user in Azure Active directory by using MSAL4J library.

```
    HttpPost create = null;
    HttpGet getRequest = null;
    HttpClient client = null;
    HttpResponse response = null;
    IAuthenticationResult result = null;

    PublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplication.builder("client_id")
            .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/").build();

    Set<String> scope = new HashSet<>();
    scope.add("User.ReadWrite.All");
    scope.add("User.ReadWrite");
    scope.add("Directory.ReadWrite");
    scope.add("Directory.ReadWrite.All");
    
    UserNamePasswordParametersBuilder parameters = UserNamePasswordParameters.builder(scope,
            "administrator@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com", "xxxxxxxx".toCharArray());

    try {
        result = pca.acquireToken(parameters.build()).join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    StringEntity inputJSONStringEntity = new StringEntity(
            "{\"passwordProfile\":{\"password\":\"User120222\"},\"country\":\"India\",\"city\":\"Mumbai\",\"displayName\":\"User1\",\"companyName\":\"companyName\",\"givenName\":\"User1\",\"jobTitle\":\"Developer\",\"accountEnabled\":true,\"streetAddress\":\"St1\",\"surname\":\"User1\",\"state\":\"MH\",\"department\":\"ESE\",\"userPrincipalName\":\"User1@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com\",\"mailNickname\":\"User1\"}");

    client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    create = new HttpPost("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");

    create.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    create.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + result.accessToken());

    create.setEntity(inputJSONStringEntity);
    response = client.execute(create);
```

Able to get token using PublicClientApplication and UserNamePasswordParameters but still getting following response after executing the request :

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Content-Type: application/json, Vary: Accept-Encoding, Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000, request-id: d3f08ea0-ee39-41fd-8f41-338392697300, client-request-id: d3f08ea0-ee39-41fd-8f41-338392697300, x-ms-ags-diagnostic: }, WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="", authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize", client_id="00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", Date: Fri, 17 Jun 2022 06:05:59 GMT] org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity@1e127982}
```

```
{"aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
"scp": "Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Directory.Write.Restricted DirectoryRecommendations.Read.All DirectoryRecommendations.ReadWrite.All Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.Read.Selected Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder Files.ReadWrite.Selected RoleAssignmentSchedule.Read.Directory RoleAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.Directory RoleEligibilitySchedule.Read.Directory RoleEligibilitySchedule.ReadWrite.Directory RoleManagement.Read.Directory RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory RoleManagementPolicy.Read.Directory RoleManagementPolicy.ReadWrite.Directory User.Export.All User.Invite.All User.ManageIdentities.All User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All profile openid email"}
```

Can someone please help to resolve this issue or any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually the 401 unauthorized error occurs , if you don't have proper permissions included in the token.
Token may not include all the permissions due to usage of incorrect endpoint with scope .As scopes are usually used with v2 endpoint.

As you can see the authorization url in the error is `authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize` which is clearly for v1 endpoint.

Please note that ***v1 endpoint*** must be requested with the ***`resource`*** parameter for graph endpoint ,without giving scopes:
some thing like below :

```
resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/
```

If you have scopes to be mentioned , you may need to use v2 endpoint :
Authorize URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

Auth Token URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

and scope is  must be having ***`/.default`*** value  like: `scope:{clientId}/.default`  or the scopes like you gave.

> Note : v2 endpoint doesnot work with resource parameter, here scopes
> are valid

Reference:[azure-ad-endpoint-comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison)